# How do I obtain Central Administration site url programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have some code (console app) running on a SharePoint farm machine, and I need the app to figure out the url of Central Administration site for that farm. I remember seeing some SharePoint API doing exactly that, but I can't find it now.

I've seen a bunch of hacks people are using for that, like looking it up in Windows registry, but I need a way via SharePoint API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in C#

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication centralWeb =
SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
```

Answer (score 9):

To expand on the answer from @RDeVaney:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication centralWeb =
    SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
string centralAdminUrl = centralWeb.Sites[0].Url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from msdn, please refer if it can answer your question

```
SPWebServiceCollection webServices = new SPWebServiceCollection(SPFarm.Local);

foreach (SPWebService webService in webServices)
{
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
    {
        if (!webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication)
        {
            get the URL here
        }
    }
}
```